# Google App Engine seems to be using wrong location

Tags: google-app-engine

I selected **us-east4**, however, the default hostname domain is **.uk.r.appspot.com**.  I tried getting the local timezone in my script and it is UK timezone.  How can I fix this?  I even tried creating a new project and it still puts me in the UK.

```
# gcloud app describe
authDomain: gmail.com
codeBucket: staging.xxxxx.appspot.com
databaseType: CLOUD_FIRESTORE
defaultBucket: xxxxx.appspot.com
defaultHostname: xxxxx.uk.r.appspot.com
featureSettings:
  splitHealthChecks: true
  useContainerOptimizedOs: true
gcrDomain: us.gcr.io
id: xxxxx
locationId: us-east4
name: apps/xxxxx
servingStatus: SERVING
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#requests_and_domains), the url is composed with the following information

*https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com*

The REGION_ID is a code that Google assigns based on the region you select when you create your [app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#region-id). As per the documentation, I understand that these regional URls **project-region.r.appspot.com** are replacing global URLs like .appspot.com.  Since the ID is optional for existing apps, you don't need to update URLs or make other changes once the region ID is available for your existing apps.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I did not select that region.  I don't see any reason why I would.   As you can see above, it has location as us-east4.    How can I change the region id? The only instructions I could find for changing it was in compute engine.  I've already tried recreating the app and there is no where in the steps where I selected UK

Comment: But I think that is the Region Id that Google assigned, it doesn't mean that is UK. For example, I did a little test and I selected the same location as you "us-east4" and I'm getting the same region ID XXXXXXXX.uk.r.appspot.com

Comment: You mean that "uk" does not mean the server is in the UK?  I'll investigate.  I noticed the code I had that was printing current time switched from local time to GMT so I assumed it was because of this, but it could have been the difference between my local python environment and GAE

Comment: All deployed GAE apps use GMT.  I'm pretty sure that `uk` does not have anything to do with the United Kingdom but would have been nice for Google to choose more informative region IDs...

Comment: Yes @gaefan, I think the same about uk. I added a comment in the documentation in order that Google update and share more information about the region id since it's a little bit confusing .